# How do you achieve a fade color blend for a nav bar with many colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Dear community i'm trying to find how this type of coloring is called and how can i achieve it (see attached image- polygon navigation bar).I probably need CSS or Javascript but i don't know how to search for it. Can somebody help me ?

[image: polygon navigation bar]

Thank You in advance

Comment: wait, you need to combine colors like in the picture ?

Comment: The search term is “CSS gradient.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code, maybe you need to use `background-blend-mode` property.

```css
.nav{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0000FF, #FF0000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #0000FF, #FF0000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #0000FF, #FF0000);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0000FF, #FF0000);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.nav ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
    <li>Menu 5</li>
  </ul>
</div
```